# Rails how to describe many to many restriction

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this :

```
model listing:
  has_many: restrictions
model user:
  has_many: restrictions
model restriction:
 belongs_to: :user
 belongs_to: :listing
```

By default all users are allowed to see **all** listings because there is **no relation between listings and users**, but I want to **restrict users** per listing if there is a record on restriction table.

For example:

If the record *restrictions.user_id: 2* and *restrictions.listing_id: 5* exits, the **user with id 2** will see all listings **except** the **listing with id 5**

How can I do/describe that with rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nesiseka answered, with a little changes, using rails where.not

```
scope :accessible_listings, ->(user) { where.not(id: Restriction.where(user_id: user.id).map(&:listing_id) ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind is having a scope in Listing model which would exclude the restricted listing:

```
scope :accessible_listings, -> { where('id != ?',Restriction.where(user_id: current_user.id).map(&:listing_id)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't this a has_many association, maybe you can define a method to do what you want

```
    class User
      def listings
        Listing.where.not(id: ((self.restrictions.map &:listing).uniq.map &:id))
      end
    end
```